# How to favorite android app Programmatically on android?

Tags: android, shell, homescreen, favorite, quicklaunch

I'm looking for a way to programmatically favorite an android app. I need to do this either in Java or in Android Shell. It doesnt matter if the method requires SU/Root or not.

By favoriting an app I mean adding a quick launch icon to the "footer" of the home screen.

Thank you very much in advance. I've spend hours on this problem and I cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: hi are you talking about to make a shortcut on home screen if yes ,i have have answer!!

Comment: No I'm not talking about making a shortcut to home screen, but making a short cut to the quick launch bar which is located in the bottom of the home screen.